# How can I change my fcitx input method from the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I am looking for a way to change the fcitx input method using a terminal command. I know I can use the hotkeys, but for the purposes of an application I am writing, I need to use a command (something similar to ibus engine [name] for ibus). I've been looking through the fcitx documentation, but haven't found anything. Anyone know of a command? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The appropriate command is `fcitx-remote -s <imname>`, where `<imname>` is of course the name `fcitx` uses to refer to the input method. Sadly, these names are not documented either, but you can find them in your `fcitx` configuration file (in my system, it's `~/.config/fcitx/profile`), where there's a list of all the enabled (also, all disabled) input methods.

In particular, the names for xkb layouts go something like `fcitx-keyboard-XYZ`. For example `fcitx-keyboard-us` for the US English QWERTY layout, or `fcitx-keyboard-de-dvorak` for a German Dvorak layout. As another example, the Mozc Japanese IM is called simply `mozc`.

The current input method (the equivalent of `ibus engine` without parameters) can be obtained from the same file, in the line that says `IMName=<imname>`. Be aware, however, that the scope of this variable depends on whether you share the state between windows or not, and on whether `fcitx` is active (the result of running `fcitx-remote`).

Comment: `fcitx-remote -t` can also be used to toggle input methods, although it doesn't seem to work when bound from the `i3wm` config file for some reason